# Como gerar um executável com todos os arquivos do meu projeto?

Tags: python, .exe

Eu preciso de dados privados que estão armazenados dentro de um arquivo binário dentro do próprio computador do usuário e para isso, quero compilar todos os arquivos junto com o código fonte dentro de um executável. Como faço isso em Python?

Quero transformar toda a pasta do meu projeto em um executável com todos os arquivos que guada os dados e o código fonte na mesma pasta do meu projeto. Dentro da pasta do meu projeto há arquivos `.py`, `.bin`, `.dat`, `.txt` e não quero que estes arquivos fiquem fora do executável.

Eu gostaria que tudo ficasse juntinho em um só arquivo `.exe`. É possível fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível!

Você irá precisar do seguinte programa (Auto Py to Exe): [https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cXQL.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resto é bem intuitivo, bastar marcas as opções e se necessário, incluir bibliotecas.

Comment: Tem outro programa em vez deste?